# Removing bias of a coin in which getting Head is a sure event

Tags: probability

Let's say we have a coin, with an unknown bias:

p(H) = x

To remove its bias we can take the following approach:

- Toss the coin two times, let's call this event A and B
- if `toss(A) == toss(B)`, discard the results.
- if `toss(A) != toss(B)`, take 1st (or 2nd, does not matter) result as
  the output

Why is this correct?

```
P(HT) = P(TH) = x*(1-x)
```

But what if the coin is biased in such a way that we always get a Head (or Tail)? How can we use this coin in such a way that it will be unbiased?

The question sounds quite stupid (as you can't get probability out of a sure event), but is there any way to solve it?

As **@lulu** rightly said, this method does not give the guarantee to produce an **unbiased** coin in limited steps. So is there any methods out there, that can produce an unbiased coin in limited number of steps?

Comment: If the coin always comes up $H$ it is still true that the probability of getting $HT$ or $TH$ is the same...both are $0$.  Remember that nobody is guaranteeing that this method of "producing" a fair coin will be practical.  If the probability of getting $T$ is $10^{-100}$ then the method works, but it will take longer than your life time to decide a single toss of your synthetic coin.

Comment: @lulu edited my question

Comment: Even for a fair coin there is no guarantee that this mechanism will produce a new fair coin in a fixed number of tries.  You could get $HH$ or $TT$ as often as you like. Very low probability of that, of course.  But perfectly possible.

Comment: @lulu Yeah it can't be determined: it is always possible for an unfair (or "biased") coin to happen to turn up exactly 10 heads in 20 flips, so fairness can only be established with certain maximum bias.

Comment: No...the algorithm is guaranteed to be perfectly fair and physically guaranteed with probability $1$ (except in the nullifying cases $p_H=0,1$).  The only problem is that it might take a really, really long time to work.  If your original coin is extremely biased, nothing is going to give a practical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always get a head, no matter what, then tossing the coin is useless for generating a random event. You can generate a "fair" coin only if you can partition the outcomes of a sequence of tosses into two sets that are equally likely.
In the case of the "always heads" coin there is no such partition.

So the exercise only makes sense if $0 < p(H) < 1.$
This is such a common assumption that it is generally taken as part of the definition of a "biased coin." (The other part, of course, is that $p(H) \neq \frac12.$)

Now suppose $p(H) = \frac13.$
We can show by contradiction that there is no bounded decision procedure to simulate a fair coin toss using this biased coin.

**Proof.** Suppose (for sake of argument) that there is such a bounded decision procedure.
Let $n$ be the maximum number of tosses in this procedure.
That is, in the decision procedure, some sequences of $n$ or fewer tosses are assigned to the result "heads." If none of those sequences occurs then the result is "tails."

There are a finite number of possible sequences of $n$ of fewer tosses, so only a finite number that can be assigned to "heads." Each sequence has a prior probability of occurring that is some integer multiple of $1/3^n.$
Therefore the total probability that a "heads" sequence will occur is some integer multiple of $1/3^n.$ Suppose it is $k/3^n.$

We have assumed that the decision procedure simulates a fair coin, that is, the probability of a "heads" result is exactly $\frac12.$
But that means we must have $k/3^n = \frac12,$
which implies $2k = 3^n$ where $k$ is an integer, which implies that $3^n$ is even.
But $3^n$ is odd for any integer $n.$
This is a contradiction, so there cannot be a decision process of the type we assumed to exist. $\square$

So there is at least one value of $p(H)$ for which no bounded decision process exists. If we *do not even know* the value of $p(H),$ only that $0 < p(H) < 1$
and $p(H) \neq \frac12,$ then we do not know whether there exists a bounded decision process. Therefore we certainly cannot *specify* a bounded decision process, since that would prove the existence of such a process.

In general, tossing a coin whose bias is unknown, it may take a large number of tosses to get to a simulated fair "heads" or "tails," and there is no way to put a limit in advance on the number of tosses.
But with probability $1,$ the sequence of tosses will end after *some* number of tosses with either a simulated "head" or a "tail" (a pair of tosses $HT$ or $TH$ of the biased coin).

Answer (score 0):

If you toss an unfair coin $n$ times, the probability of getting at least $p$ heads is:

$$
P_n(p) = \sum_{k=0}^p {x^k(1-x)^{n-k}} \binom{n}{k}
$$

There is no exact but "efficient" method to compute this that I'm aware of.

Consider that your "fairer" trial is: Throwing an unfair coin $n$ times, and check if the number of heads is smaller (or larger) than $p$. If $P_n(p)=1/2$ the trial is perfectly fair.

Note that if $P_n(p)$ is smaller than 1/2, you can increase $p$. If both $P_n(p)<1/2$ and $P_n(p+1)>1/2$ then you have the optimal $p$ for the given number of tosses. But if the "accuracy" of this method is insufficient, you can increase the number of tosses ($n$), until you reach a satisfying level of fairness.

As you may have intuitively foreseen, we need to assume $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq 1$, otherwise the fairness error is always 1/2.